Wireless communication with ROS2 Jazzy and UR arms
I am building a mobile robot using Jazzy with the Nav2 stack, with my custom nodes on top. I have it such that the robot moves between two dock points, waiting at each one for user input.
Currently, that input is a button press on a wireless gamepad, but I would like to be able to send and receive simple commands / data wirelessly to a set of robotic arms. These arms have GPIO pins I would like to use, with it being as simple as a pin pulled high when the arm is ready for the robot to leave, and another pin pulled high when the robot is at the arm.
What would be the best way to achieve this kind of functionality? The solutions I have found all rely on either Bluetooth or WiFi networks, and I would prefer it to be as simple to connect to one of these arms as possible, without the need for complicated networking.
Any suggestions for hardware / software that could do this would be appreciated.

Are you trying to do this purely off ros topics? If so, wifi really would be the most simple. Bluetooth is also extremely simple to implement, especially if you consider arduino platforms. What complications have you found with the above that make them undesirable?

WiFi is not preferred as there are concerns about network security in the application, as well as the need for it to be drop in per robot and arm pair.
The issue with bluetooth, at least with what I have found, is that there will be 2 arms for each robot, meaning the BT's would need to constantly pair and unpair every pass. I am evaluating a BT solution currently.
The general idea, and what I am trying to find, is a short range solution which requires little to no setup, such that the physical closeness of the robot to the arm is the primary "pairing" mechanism.

Realistically what you're describing is either bluetooth or wifi. If you have security concerns with wifi you 100% should not be using bluetooth. Plenty of wifi protocols exist that fit most operating use cases, and if you need something more secure than that, you won't be able to find something with "little to no setup".
